# Do the USER and WORKDIR instructions hold in downstream docker file?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have 2 docker images, the first Dockerfile creates a user using:

```
RUN useradd -m newuser
```

then it switches to the user and workspace as follows:

```
USER newuser
WORKDIR /home/newuser/
```

The second docker file reads from the first image using the FROM statement.

Should the `USER` and `WORKDIR` instructions still hold in the second file without having to put them in again?

Comment: I did, and it didn't work for me, but I am being told this should work as described. I just wanted to confirm which way it should be working

Comment: Could you share your dockerfiles and detail your process?

Answer (score 9):

From this Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:8

ENV HOME /home/user
RUN useradd --create-home --home-dir $HOME user \
    && mkdir -p $HOME \
    && chown -R user:user $HOME

WORKDIR $HOME
USER user
```

A build and a run later:

```
$docker build -t deb .
$docker run --rm deb bash -c "pwd && whoami"
/home/user
user
```

---

Now from this Dockerfile, based from the previous image:

```
FROM deb
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh" ]
```

Build and run:

```
$docker build -t debb .
$docker run --rm -it debb
[container]$ pwd && whoami
/home/user
user
```

So, yes the `USER` and the `WORKDIR` are *inherited*.

---

```
Client:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 15:38:58 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 15:38:58 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```